# Whats is the best way to find the common prefix for String(s)?

Tags: java, spring

I need to find a way to find the common prefix for a string(s), for example:

The strings can be appended with either 2 or 4 characters like so:

hello12
hello1234

Sometimes though, the strings can also end up like so:

hello11
hello1122

But the common prefix is now hello11 and it should only be hello. I also need to be able to get hello from the string when there is only one string.

I have written the following code below and it works when ALL strings are unique and do not have any common appended values.

String prefix = "";

```
if(listStrings.size() > 0) {
  prefix = listStrings.get(0);

  for(int i = 1; i < listStrings.size(); i++) {
    String nextString = listStrings.get(i);
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < Math.min(prefix.length(), listStrings.get(i).length()); j++) {
      if(prefix.charAt(j) != nextString.charAt(j)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    prefix = listStrings.get(i).substring(0, j);
  }
}
```

This code produces hello when the following inputs are:

hello1234
hello5678
hellothere

It doesn't give me hello when the following inputs are:

hello1122
hello1124
hello1124
hello1134

I expect the output to be "hello" no matter what is input into the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that just looking at all kinds of characters is the wrong approach.

You basically stated: I want my prefix to NOT contain digits.

In other words: when collecting your max prefix, you should stop looking at any string as soon as you encounter the first character that doesn't match your criteria (which seems to be: the character represents a digit). You could rely on the [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class and its `isDigit()` method for that.

But the real point here: you need to clarify your requirements. If you are unable to clearly express the exact definition of your "prefixes", then writing java code is the wrong priority. In other words: are we talking about letters here, versus digits? What about whitespaces? Pure "ASCII" or beware, arbitrary Unicode?

Thus the real answer is: step back, and make up your mind *conceptually* what constitutes a valid prefix, and what exactly tells you "the prefix just ended here".

Comment: No, the string can be made up completely of letters too, see the example above. The rules are the String can either be appended by 2 or 4 characters, I just need to extract the common prefix whether its from a list of strings or just a standalone variable.

Comment: And that doesn't make sense. Then "hello11" would be the common prefix. Again: your rules are incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get prefix without digits you can do next:

```
for (j = 0; j < Math.min(prefix.length(), listStrings.get(i).length()); j++) {
                    int symCode = (int) prefix.charAt(j);
                    if (prefix.charAt(j) != nextString.charAt(j) ||
                            !((symCode > 64 && symCode < 91) || (symCode > 96 && symCode < 123))) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```